# What is wrong with my graph iterator via DFS?

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, iterator

I have been trying to make simple `DFS` using object oriented design and by implementing the `Iterator` class. But `DFS` does not work as it should.

I have almost tried everything that I could but I was not able to make this work.

Also I couldn't find much relevant info on internet about the type of code I am trying.

I have two interfaces `Vertex` and `Graph`.

Following is the code I am trying:

```
public class GraphIterator implements Iterator<Vertex> {
  private Graph g;
  private Vertex v;
  private Stack<Vertex> stack;
  private Set<Vertex> colored;

  public GraphIterator(Graph g, Vertex v) {
      this.g = g;
      this.v = v;
      stack = new Stack<>();
      colored = new TreeSet<>();
      stack.push(v);
      colored.add(v);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean hasNext() {
    return stack.isEmpty();
  }

  @Override
  public Vertex next() {
    Vertex u = stack.pop();

    for(Vertex vertex : g.getNeighbours(u)) {
        if(vertex != null && !colored.contains(vertex))
            stack.add(vertex);
    }

    return stack.pop();
  }
}
```

This is the code in `main()` I am trying to test with:

```
GraphClass g = new GraphClass();
Vertex v = new VertexClass(0);
Vertex w = new VertexClass(1);
g.addVertex(v);
g.addVertex(w);
g.addEdge(v, w);
Iterator<Vertex> it = new GraphIterator(g, v);
System.out.println(v+" vs "+it.next());
System.out.println(it.hasNext());
System.out.println(w+" vs "+it.next());
```

I know I am doing something wrong with the `DFS` algorithm but I am not able to quite understand what and where am I going wrong?

I am mostly sure that I am doing something wrong with `DFS` algorithm, which needs to be implemented using overriden methods from `Iterator` class. I would also appreciate some tips of how to do so.

I would appreciate if someone could help me in this algorithm.

Comment: Can you show a unit test? What does the graph look like?

Comment: @cricket_007 I have no unit tests for now, it's just an undirected simple graph with Vertex(s)

Comment: Okay, then can you show an example graph input?

Comment: Did you implement equals and hashcode on the vertex implementation class? Otherwise the set contains method won't work

Comment: Providing the complete runnable / testable code, would be much easier for both you and others to help on the question, and a test case would make things clearer & easier.

Comment: @cricket_007 yes everything is implemented and checked, I am just having difficulties with the algorithm to be implemented in this way (by implementing the Iterator class). I am adding the code in main() which I am trying to check, for better understanding.

Comment: @EricWang yes I have added the code which I am using in `main()`

Answer (score 1):

**Possible improvements to the code in question:**

- In `next()`, maybe just `return u;`, instead of `return stack.pop();`.
  Because that would pop 2 elements in a single call to `next()`, and with the second's neighbor vertices unchecked.
- `LinkedList` might be a better choice than `Stack` here.
  Since there seems has no need for concurrent control.

**BTW:**

- `LinkedList` is also a *stack*, it's not thread-safe; while `Stack` is thread-safe.
- *(If could post the code in a block, that others can copy & run directly, and see the output, then probably a better answer could be provided.)*